# latex beamer columns not aligned

Tags: beamer

I'm using the columns environment in latex: I split the slide in two columns, I put a figure on the left column and I write some text on the column on the right. I provide (1) my code to replicate the issue and (2) a screenshot of the result. As you can see, the columns are badly positioned. How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[english,handout]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulem}
     \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Example II}
    \begin{columns}[t] % Specify the columns and their alignment (t=top)
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{Plots/messner_1}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Item A
                    \item Item B
                    \item Item C
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `T`op aligned columns instead of `t`op. To quote the beamer user guide:

> `T` is similar to the `t` option, but `T` aligns the tops of the first lines while `t` aligns the so-called baselines of the first lines. If strange things seem to happen in conjunction with the `t` option (for example if a graphic suddenly "drops down" with the `t` option instead of "going up"), try using this [`T`] option instead.

```
\documentclass[english,handout]{beamer}
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
     \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Example II}
    \begin{columns}[T] % Specify the columns and their alignment (t=top)
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Item A
                    \item Item B
                    \item Item C
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```